# A word to express 'to temper expectations' or 'to buffer something'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to figure out a word that expresses the idea of "tempering expectations" or "buffering" something. I've heard the word in the past, but I really can't figure out what it is, so I'm hoping the hivemind would know. I think it starts with a *b*, but I can't be sure.

A sample usage is:

> I would [verb] that by saying that the results are still inconclusive, but they're interesting nonetheless.

---

I searched the thesaurus for *temper* and *moderate* — here's the entry for *temper*:

> *their idealism is tempered with realism*: moderate, modify, modulate, mitigate, alleviate, reduce, weaken, lighten, soften.

None of these exactly speak to it, but the first few close (especially moderate). The rest aren't on target.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with using *temper* in this context, but ***underplay, downplay, play down, tone down*** might work. Or just ***qualify***.

Comment: The standard term used to fill in your blank is "***qualify***".

Comment: If you want something beginning with B you could use 'balance'.

Comment: Perhaps _subdue_. For example, you can subdue expectations or feelings. (and it has B in it.)

Comment: "Temper your expectations" reminds me of "curb your enthusiasm"

Answer (score 2):

> I would **qualify** that by saying that the results are still inconclusive, but they're interesting nonetheless.

**Qualify**: (tr) to make less strong, harsh, or violent; moderate or restrict (fr. the Free Dictionary)

Comment: ah, I see now that my wise colleagues have already suggested this solution in the comments...

Answer (score -5):

Bolster?

Jimmy had to bolster his expectations because he clearly would never date higher than a 3.

Comment: That would have the opposite sense. It would mean to build up or increase expectations.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Answers should be justified by corroborative evidence such as a dictionary entry. If you can find one for *bolster* where that means "moderate, modify, modulate, mitigate, alleviate, reduce, weaken, lighten, soften" then please edit your answer to include it.